# Adding symbols around a debug section causes binary to triple in size

Tags: linker, debug-symbols, osdev, lld, zig

I would like to add a start and end symbol around each debug info section so that I can access them from my program. I tried the following scheme:

```
.debug.info ALIGN(4K) : {
    DEBUG_INFO_START = .;
    *(.debug.info)
    DEBUG_INFO_END = .;
}
.debug.abbrev ALIGN(4K) : {
    DEBUG_ABBREV_START = .;
    *(.debug.abbrev)
    DEBUG_ABBREV_END = .;
}
/* etc. */
```

But that causes each section (including .text, .rodata etc.) and the resulting binary to triple in size. What could be causing this? As you can see from the dumps below, the debug info is included in both cases so that isn't what's causing the increase in size.

I'm using Zig and the LLVM toolchain.

[Link](https://github.com/SamTebbs33/pluto/blob/c1fc74d7693ed76c4a512334eaadc7f8a532bd77/link.ld) to the whole link script. [Link](https://gist.github.com/SamTebbs33/0a4aaac08212da421a1ac2878dbf2646) to a dump of the binary without the link script modifications, [link](https://gist.github.com/2dd81e3347171a3ca2578bc8997d26e7) to a dump with the modifications.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, just an inquiry. Why do you want to output the debug info to the binary? I ask because it seems like what you are doing is a possible solution to another problem you had. I'd be curious to understand the `why` on this.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I would like my kernel to be able to print stack traces, so I need to know where the debug info is. My current workaround is to get grub to tell me where the elf section header was loaded, but unfortunately it seems like grub doesn't load the debug sections, just the .text, .bss etc.